# How can i display images and videos (from app resources) repeatedly on the app without stick the UI

Tags: java, android

I need to do app like slideshow of images and vidoes from fiels from the device.
I have tried several projects - but no one can display videos.
What is the best way to do ot. All I need is to display, repeatedly, images and videos from the devices without the UI will stuck

There are some of the projects that i tried:
https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider
https://github.com/marvinlabs/android-slideshow-widget

Thank you

Comment: We are not here to do your work for you. Why don't you first figure out how to play videos and then worry about how exactly you are going to display them in your app. It's not that complicated, you just need to take smaller steps.

Comment: your UI has been stuck because you are using too much images i mean you are using images in large size you need an image with less then 10kb

Comment: i know how to play videos, and i know how to show images.
but i dont know how can I change the image to video and reverse

Answer (score 1):

I am showing a list of videos:
The `Activity` code:

```
public class VideoListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView lvVideos;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_list);

        lvVideos = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvVideos);
        lvVideos.setAdapter(new VideosListAdapter(this));

    }
}
```

The adapter code:

```
public class VideosListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    private ArrayList<VideoData> listVideoData = new ArrayList<>();
    private String[] creationDates = new String[0];

    public VideosListAdapter(VideoListActivity videoListActivity) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) videoListActivity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // here is a listVideoData  and the creationDates  initialisation code.
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listVideoData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listVideoData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (vi == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_video, null);
        }
        VideoData videoData = listVideoData.get(position);
        VideoView videoView = (VideoView)vi.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        videoView.setVideoPath(videoData.getVideoFilePath());

        TextView tvDate = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        tvDate.setText(creationDates[position]);

        TextView tvInfo = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvPuppetInfo);
        tvInfo.setText("Whatever you want" );


        // must add this: -otherwise I don't know why, but is not working the click
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)videoView.getParent();
        relativeLayout.setClickable(true);
        relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(rlClickListener);

        return vi;
    }


    View.OnClickListener rlClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            VideoView videoView = (VideoView)v.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
                videoView.start();

        }
    };
}
```

A code part in the `row_video.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <!-- Yes, it is in pixel, hardcoded, because this is what is requested -->
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="1280px"
        android:layout_height="720px"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="25/12/2016 12:59:59"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/red_check"
        android:text="whatever you want"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvStatus"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvDate"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope it worth an upvote ! ( click )